# Unity: Get excact time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello I want to get the excact time. But if I use Time.time I get something like this: "7.45" but I want something like this "7.4597646". Can somebody help me pls.

Comment: Show your code because in my test I have high precision with Time.time, like 3.234684

Comment: Btw `Time.time` is the time in seconds since app start .. if you actually want the current time use `DateTime.Now` note that Unity `Debug.Log` rounds floats automatically optimised for better readability ... See [Thomas's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64661383/7111561)  below for how to log with more precision. Besides that you can be sure that the value itself has its float precision and will calculate accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You get the precise time. What might mislead you is that your editor (or output) might round the result to display it in a easier readable manner.

You can print it with higher precision using a [formated string](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings):

```
Debug.Log(Time.time.ToString("F5"));
```